# Setting textSize programmatically

Tags: android

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font));
```

The following code works, but the `R.dimen.result_font` is taken as a much bigger value than it really is. Its maybe about 18sp-22sp or 24sp according to the screen size ... But the size set here is at least about 50sp. Can someone please recommend something ?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You have to change it to `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` because `getDimension(id)` returns a dimen value from resources and **implicitly** converted to **px**.

Java:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                     getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font));
```

Kotlin:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                     resources.getDimension(R.dimen.result_font))
```

Comment: why not to use getResources().getDimensionPixelSize() ?

Comment: @Nizzy It's actually same. The difference is the return type. Since the second paramater of `setTextSize()` requires `float` value, `getDimension()` is a good choice.

Comment: What about padding?

Comment: @sachithkn The 4 parameters of `setPadding()` (start, top, end, bottom) requires values as pixels too. `getDimension()` returned as pixel value. For example, I have 4dp resource with name `small_margin`, when I call `getDimension(R.dimen.small_margin)` it will return the product of 4dp and density of device (4dp * density). Let's say the device is Nexus 5, its density is xxhdpi, scaling factor of xxhdpi is 3, so the method will return 4dp * 3.0.

Answer (score 12):

**Requirement**

Suppose we want to set textView Size programmatically from a resource file.

**Dimension resource file** (res/values/dimens.xml)

```
<resources>     
   <dimen name="result_font">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**Solution**

First get **dimen** value from resource file into a variable "textSizeInSp".

```
int textSizeInSp = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font);
```

Next convert **16** sp value into equal pixels.

for that create a method.

```
 public static float convertSpToPixels(float sp, Context context) {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**Let's set TextSize,**

```
textView.setTextSize(convertSpToPixels(textSizeInSp , getApplicationContext()));
```

**All together,**

```
int textSizeInSp = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font);
textView.setTextSize(convertSpToPixels(textSizeInSp , getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I think `getDimension` returns a pixel value not SP value, as also mentioned in the accepted answer