# How to change a ListView item's font size?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am able to change my `ListItem`'s text size in xml:

```
 android:textSize="22sp"
```

But instead of hard coding it in xml, how do I do it through java?

here is my adapter:

```
 BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, Library.getInstance().getBible(bible).getBook(pos).getChapters());
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting textSize programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364993/setting-textsize-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to the TextView in XML:

```
android:id="@+id/text"
```

In Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View item = (View) adapter.getItem(i);
    TextView text = item.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 22f); //or whatever size you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom layout xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

java code

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
MobileMuni.getBookmarkStore().getRecentLocations()) {
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
textView.setTextSize(12);

return textView;
 }
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this line:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,25);
```